# match a number using regex for comma separated number

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, csv, select

I have a string that contains number with separated by comma like below.

> 15,22,20,26,33,445,40,44,22,225,115,2

I want to know if a number say `15` is in that string or not.
The problem is that `15` and `115` both are a match.
Same for other number say `2`, for this case `20` , `25`, and `225` are match.
For both cases only it should return if there is `15` or `2` in the string.
I tried using `like` keyword but it's not working. It also return the rows with `115` or `20, 225, 222` 
whille matching `15 and 2` respectively. 
Can anyone suggest a `regex` pattern?
**Update**
I have a query like below where I was using `like` keyword, but I was getting wrong result for above reason.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id,A.title,A.title_hi,A.cId,B.id as cid1,A.report_type ,A.icon_img_url, A.created_at , A.news_date 
FROM tfs_report_news A, tfs_commodity_master B
WHERE (',' + RTRIM(A.cId) + ',') LIKE ('%,' + B.id + ',%')
AND A.ccId = B.ccId AND A.`report_type`= "M" 
AND A.isDeleted=0 AND A.isActive=1 AND B.isDeleted=0 
AND B.status=1 
AND A.news_date= (SELECT MAX(T.news_date) 
FROM tfs_report_news T WHERE (',' + RTRIM(T.cId) + ',') 
LIKE ('%,' + B.id + ',%'))
ORDER BY created_at desc, id desc limit 100;
```

Here `tfs_report_news` has the string `15,22,20,26,33,445,40,44,22,225,115,2` as column name 
`cId` and individual `cId` like `15` or `2` is `id` of `tfs_commodity_master`

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers as strings!  Don't store multiple values in a string column!

Comment: I know that @GordonLinoff. It's design flaw in the schema, but I can't make any change there. It's an old app, a lot of business logic depends on this table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, what you asked for is the purpose of [string function `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

> Returns a value in the range of `1` to `N` if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of `N` substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `,` characters [...] Returns `0` if `str` is not in `strlist` or if `strlist` is the empty string. Returns `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`.

So to check if a value is present in the list, you can just do:

```
find_in_set('15', '15,22,20,26,33,445,40,44,22,225,115,2') > 0
```

Side note: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/10676716)** is a recommended reading.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET('15', csv) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

Another option would be to use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CONCAT(',', csv, ',') LIKE '%,15,%' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

Finally, you could also use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN csv REGEXP '[[:<:]]15[[:>:]]' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: It would be kind of you explaining `'[[:<:]]15[[:>:]]'`

Comment: Note that MySQL 8.0.4 changed their regular expression library, one consequence of which is that `[[:<:]]` syntax is not supported anymore. You must use `\\b` for word boundaries. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility for other changes.